# How can I **EASILY** install this Mac OS X on a bunch of Macs without downloading the whole thing every time?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I am a Linux guy, and I have to provide support for about 15 Mac users. I need to install this OSX 10.8.x and I got the license codes all sent to me. But I can't figure out how to get whatever file on mine, so I can re-use it. How do I do that?

Do I really have to go through this whole registration info where I have to enter a credit card and everything else about me before I can get access to anything?

Comment: Is your question about downloading the installer as your title implies, about the setup/first login process, as the body of your question implies, or both? Are the machines the same hardware? Are you doing a clean install or trying to preserve existing data?

Comment: If the linked question doesn't answer your question, please edit to clarify how you are asking something different and we can reopen this.

Comment: I too am not clear on what is being asked.  I assume you're asking if you need to download Mountain Lion from the app store on each of the 15 Macs.  If so then the answer is no, you can download it once, use the "How to create a customer Mountain Lion Installer" link above for instructions on how to make an installer, then use that installer to deploy it to each of the 15 Macs.

Comment: OS X does not have license codes?

Comment: He means download codes that can be redeemed in the MacStore. They can be repurchased in Apple stores or over the phone or through volume license scheme. We use them at work too.